# Converting EditText into Int

Tags: c#, android, string, android-edittext, int

I am getting the user to input their height and weight into an `EditText` and then calculate their BMI. I am trying to convert the `EditText` into an `int` so I can do the calculation.

```
 EditText userHeight = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextHeight);
 EditText userWeight = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextWeight);


 int intuserweight = Convert.ToInt32(userWeight.Text);
 intuserweight = int.Parse(userWeight.Text);

 int intuserheight = Int32.Parse(userHeight.Text);
```

I have tried both conversions and both state `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format`.

Edit Full code for Enter Intake Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace AndroidDoctorApp
 {
[Activity(Label = "Enter Intake")]
public class EnterIntake : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.EnterIntake);



        EditText userDate = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextDate);
        EditText userTime = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextTime);
        EditText userHeight = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextHeight);
        EditText userWeight = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextWeight);

        Button btnBMI = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCalcBMI);
        Button btnAddHistory = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonAddHistory);
        Button btnViewHistory = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonViewHistory);




        int bmi;
        int intuserweight = int.Parse(userWeight.Text.ToString());
       // intuserweight = int.Parse(userWeight.Text);


        int intuserheight = Int32.Parse(userHeight.Text);

        bmi = intuserweight / (intuserheight * intuserheight);


        btnBMI.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {

            string toast = string.Format("Your BMI is:  ", bmi);
            Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();


        };



        btnAddHistory.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {

            string toast = string.Format("BMI Added to History ");
            Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();

        };


    }
}
```

}

Comment: You may first want to check how the `userWeight.Text` look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
int userweight = int.Parse(userWeight.getText().toString());
```

edit
     int bmi;
     int intuserweight;
     int intuserheight;

```
    btnBMI.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
       intuserweight = int.Parse(userWeight.Text.ToString());
       intuserheight = int.Parse(userHeight.Text.ToString());

    bmi = intuserweight / (intuserheight * intuserheight);
        string toast = string.Format("Your BMI is:  ", bmi);
        Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    };
```

Try this. Sorry for any syntactical errors(if any) as I am a Java guy not much in C#. And donot forget to tell if it works.

Comment: yes Ive tried this but getText isn't coming up 
'Android.Widget.EditText' does not contain a definition for 'getText' and no extension method 'getText' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Widget.EditText' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: then use .Text.toString()

Comment: Ive tried it and it came up with same error 
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
 int userweight = int.Parse(userWeight.Text.ToString());

Comment: Try to print the value of weight. Check what is the value returning?

Comment: Because its a editText box in Visual Studio to allow user input in android. And i printed out the input and nothing was showing.

Comment: try this:    EditText userWeight =(EditText) FindViewById(Resource.Id.editTextWeight);

Comment: can you check the names of files in Gen folder in project explorer

Comment: Is there R.java file? or Resource.java?

Comment: I'm  using C# to develop the android app. Its Visual Studio with Xamarin so no .Java files

Comment: refresh/ rebuild your project. I think the problem is with build or something then. and do check your "editTextWeight" entry in your resource file

Comment: I've tried and checked everything still same error.

Comment: can you show the xml code where you created editText

Comment: <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextHeight"
        android:hint="Enter Height - m" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextWeight"
        android:hint="Enter Weight - kg"
        android:inputType="number" />

Comment: how are you calling this class can you give the full code. edit that in your question

Comment: Yes that worked fine thanks. Also I had to add this to make it display ~
  string toast = string.Format("Your BMI is: {0}", bmi); That {0} made it display the BMI on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You try something like

```
int user_Weight=Integer.parseInt(userheight.gettext().toString());
```